# Elixir Enum member? for multiple elements

Tags: enums, elixir

`Enum.member/2` is only able to check for one elements membership. Like

`Enum.member ["abc", "def", "ghi", "123", "hello"], "abc" -> true`

Is there a way to use an anonymous function, etc. for checking membership of multiple items, and returning false if one of the elements is not included to stay DRY and avoid something like this?

```
Enum.member ["abc", "def", "ghi", "123", "hello"], "abc"
Enum.member ["abc", "def", "ghi", "123", "hello"], "def"
Enum.member ["abc", "def", "ghi", "123", "hello"], "ghi"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Enum.all?/2` (if you want all items to be present) or `Enum.any?/2` (if you want any one item to be present) + `Enum.member?/2` (or the `in` operator, which does the same):

```
iex(1)> list = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "123", "hello"]
["abc", "def", "ghi", "123", "hello"]
iex(2)> Enum.all?(["abc", "def", "ghi"], fn x -> x in list end)
true
iex(3)> Enum.any?(["abc", "def", "ghi"], fn x -> x in list end)
true
iex(4)> Enum.all?(["abc", "z"], fn x -> x in list end)
false
iex(5)> Enum.any?(["abc", "z"], fn x -> x in list end)
true
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to work with sets, then check with `MapSet.subset?/2`

```
iex(1)> list = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "123", "hello"]
["abc", "def", "ghi", "123", "hello"]

iex(2)> MapSet.subset?(MapSet.new(["abc", "def", "ghi"]), MapSet.new(list))
true

iex(3)> MapSet.subset?(MapSet.new(["abc", "def", "jkl"]), MapSet.new(list))
false
```